# Xamarin Forms Children Cannot be Evaluated

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get data from an api that has an endpoint showing data and also children of that data. In the generic repository code, I deserialize the json, I get all of the json data including the children.  When I then return the json, the data is blank.  How do I get the data to return?

Models

```
public class CaseStaffJoin    {
    public int caseStaffJoinId { get; set; } 
    public int sxCaseId { get; set; } 
    public int staffId { get; set; } 
    public string staff { get; set; } 
    public string staffType { get; set; } 
}

public class ComplicationPhysicianJoin    {
    public int complicationPhysicianJoinId { get; set; } 
    public int caseComplicationJoinId { get; set; } 
    public int physicianId { get; set; } 
    public string physician { get; set; } 
}

public class CaseComplicationJoin    {
    public int caseComplicationJoinId { get; set; } 
    public int sxCaseId { get; set; } 
    public int complicationSubsectionId { get; set; } 
    public string complicationOtherText { get; set; } 
    public string complicationSubsection { get; set; } 
    public List<ComplicationPhysicianJoin> complicationPhysicianJoin { get; set; } 
}

public class ProcedurePhysicianJoin    {
    public int procedurePhysicianJoinId { get; set; } 
    public int sxCaseProcedureJoinId { get; set; } 
    public int physicianId { get; set; } 
    public string physician { get; set; } 
}

public class SxCaseProcedureJoin    {
    public int sxCaseProcedureJoinId { get; set; } 
    public int sxCaseId { get; set; } 
    public string procedureTypeOtherText { get; set; } 
    public int procedureTypeId { get; set; } 
    public string procedureType { get; set; } 
    public List<ProcedurePhysicianJoin> procedurePhysicianJoin { get; set; } 
}

public class ReturnOr    {
    public int returnOrId { get; set; } 
    public int sxCaseId { get; set; } 
    public DateTime date { get; set; } 
    public string surgeon { get; set; } 
    public string facility { get; set; } 
    public string surgery { get; set; } 
    public int reasonId { get; set; } 
    public string reasonOther { get; set; } 
    public int linktoDbRecord { get; set; } 
    public bool @internal { get; set; } 
    public string reason { get; set; } 
}

public class Sig    {
    public int sigId { get; set; } 
    public int sxCaseId { get; set; } 
    public string sig1 { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public int sxCaseId { get; set; } 
    public DateTime dos { get; set; } 
    public string record { get; set; } 
    public bool complication { get; set; } 
    public bool returnOr { get; set; } 
    public string uniqueId { get; set; } 
    public int eyeId { get; set; } 
    public bool review { get; set; } 
    public bool complete { get; set; } 
    public string userId { get; set; } 
    public string facesheet { get; set; } 
    public int physicianId { get; set; } 
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string eye { get; set; } 
    public string physician { get; set; } 
    public List<CaseStaffJoin> caseStaffJoin { get; set; } 
    public List<CaseComplicationJoin> caseComplicationJoin { get; set; } 
    public List<SxCaseProcedureJoin> sxCaseProcedureJoin { get; set; } 
    public List<ReturnOr> returnOrs { get; set; } 
    public List<Sig> sig { get; set; } 
}
```

Service

```
public class SxCasesDetailsDataService : ISxCasesDetailsDataService
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository _genericRepository;
    
    public SxCasesDetailsDataService(IGenericRepository genericRepository)
    {
        _genericRepository = genericRepository;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Root>> GetSxCaseListAsync()
    {
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(ApiConstants.BaseApiUrl)
        {
            Path = ApiConstants.SxCaseEndpoint
        };

        var sxCases = await _genericRepository.GetAsync<List<Root>>(builder.ToString());


        return sxCases;
    }

    }}}
```

ViewModel

```
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ISxCaseDataService _sxCaseDataService;

    private ObservableCollection<Root> _sxCases;

    private Root _selectedSxCase;

    public HomeViewModel(IConnectionService connectionService,
        INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService,
        ISxCaseDataService sxCaseDataService)
        : base(connectionService, navigationService, dialogService)
    {
        _sxCaseDataService = sxCaseDataService;

        SxCases = new ObservableCollection<Root>();
        

        
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Root> SxCases
    {
        get => _sxCases;
        set => SetProperty(ref _sxCases, value);
    }



    public override async Task InitializeAsync(object data)
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        SxCases = (await _sxCaseDataService.GetSxCaseListAsync()).ToObservableCollection();
        
        IsBusy = false;
    }

   
}
```

Generic Repository

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient(uri);
            string jsonResult = string.Empty;

            var responseMessage = await Policy
                .Handle<WebException>(ex =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name + " : " + ex.Message}");
                    return true;
                })
                .WaitAndRetryAsync
                (
                    5,
                    retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))
                )
                .ExecuteAsync(async () => await httpClient.GetAsync(uri));

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                jsonResult =
                    await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                **//This is where the json is deserialized and seems to be correct
                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResult);
                //When the data is returned here it is blank
                return json;**
            }

            if (responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden ||
                responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                throw new ServiceAuthenticationException(jsonResult);
            }

            throw new HttpRequestExceptionEx(responseMessage.StatusCode, jsonResult);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{ e.GetType().Name + " : " + e.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

JSON

[
{
"sxCaseId": 0,
"dos": "2021-01-11T01:15:44.170Z",
"record": "string",
"complication": true,
"returnOr": true,
"uniqueId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
"eyeId": 0,
"review": true,
"complete": true,
"userId": "string",
"facesheet": "string",
"physicianId": 0,
"name": "string",
"eye": "string",
"physician": "string",
"caseStaffJoin": [
{
"caseStaffJoinId": 0,
"sxCaseId": 0,
"staffId": 0,
"staff": "string",
"staffType": "string"
}
],
"caseComplicationJoin": [
{
"caseComplicationJoinId": 0,
"sxCaseId": 0,
"complicationSubsectionId": 0,
"complicationOtherText": "string",
"complicationSubsection": "string",
"complicationPhysicianJoin": [
{
"complicationPhysicianJoinId": 0,
"caseComplicationJoinId": 0,
"physicianId": 0,
"physician": "string"
}
]
}
],
"sxCaseProcedureJoin": [
{
"sxCaseProcedureJoinId": 0,
"sxCaseId": 0,
"procedureTypeOtherText": "string",
"procedureTypeId": 0,
"procedureType": "string",
"procedurePhysicianJoin": [
{
"procedurePhysicianJoinId": 0,
"sxCaseProcedureJoinId": 0,
"physicianId": 0,
"physician": "string"
}
]
}
],
"returnOrs": [
{
"returnOrId": 0,
"sxCaseId": 0,
"date": "2021-01-11T01:15:44.170Z",
"surgeon": "string",
"facility": "string",
"surgery": "string",
"reasonId": 0,
"reasonOther": "string",
"linktoDbRecord": 0,
"internal": true,
"reason": "string"
}
],
"sig": [
{
"sigId": 0,
"sxCaseId": 0,
"sig1": "string"
}
]
}
]

Comment: You have given a very high level overview of what you are doing, and very limited error information. Is this line `_genericRepository.GetAsync` throwing the error? If not which line is it

Comment: what **specific** line throws the exception, and what is the **specific** exception that is thrown?  Where is the code that actually makes the service call?  Where is the json returned by the service?

Comment: @Jason I added the section under generic respository where I am deserializing the json.  I am able to get the json at this point, but where I return json, I get no data.

Comment: @00110001  I added the section under generic respository where I am deserializing the json. I am able to get the json at this point, but where I return json, I get no data.

Comment: Where is the actual json?  Most likely it does not match your model

Comment: @Jason I've added the json.  I used a converter to create the models.

Comment: Where is the code for SxCaseDetail?

Comment: @Jason Sorry, I forgot to modify the Service and ViewModel code when I revised the question.  I've updated the code.

Comment: That appears to match the model.  I would suggest creating a simple test that just deserializes the json into your model, and eliminates all the layers of generics and helpers,  Verify and debug that simple process first, then incorporate any changes into your app

Comment: @Brady Paste the json data via the way with VS. VS> Edit> Paste Special> Paste JSON As Classes. It would generate the matching classes. I tested with my code and json data.  It works well. But on your json data, it would return a list with no data. Please check your json again.